# How much time google analytic take to update a goal?

Tags: google-analytics

I am facing a problem in GA analytic. My own analytics tells the different thing about no. of user made sign up while GA tell something else.

This is the goal designation codmedialert.com/accounts/register/complete/

The funneling is like

1. codmedialert.com/accounts/register/
2. codmedialert.com/accounts/register/complete/
3. codmedialert.com/accounts/activate/complete/

Is it something wrong with the goal created or analytics is telling me wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programing related

Answer (score 1):

You can get immediate results by going to realtime->conversions.
For the rest of reports it takes few hours, you just have to set the date range to "today"

Impossible to know anything else by viewing only the urls you posted, please debug by using the real time view

Comment: Also, if you define a funnel it becomes available immediately, data may start appearing in three hours, though it can take 48 hours for data to be fully processed.